# The reason for sudo when installing on mac via command line

Tags: macos, command-line, installation, yeoman, sudo

Why do my macs require me to type `sudo` before command line installs?

For example, the [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/gettingstarted.html) website says to run the command `npm install -g yo` but it fails unless I type sudo as a prefix `sudo npm install -g yo`.

The same thing happens while installing compass or nodejs.

It's not like typing `sudo` is a big deal, but it appears not everyone is required to follow this step.
Is there something I can do to avoid this?

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue.

See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151018/npm-throws-error-without-sudo).

Comment: I seen that thread previously, it actually didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the reason is simple: sudo means that you need root(admin) privileges. Thats to avoid that anybody can install softwares on your system. And I am not just talking about people, but more about softwares. It avoids that an other programm can install maleware/virus etc without your permission. It is actually a pretty good thing ;)

Comment: Ok makes sense, so you recommend keeping the sudo? I'll accept this answer.

Comment: For sure. It is alway recommendet to NOT use a root account. With sudo you can avoid a lot of security problems. On windows is sudo the "run as admin" window. It's almost the same.